# C++ custom iterator and (*this)

Tags: c++, iterator

I am definining a custom iterator

```
class row_iterator {
    // To iterate over nodes.
    friend class Hamiltonian;
    public:
        typedef row_iterator                 self_type;
        typedef int                          value_type;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag    iterator_category;
        row_iterator( const Bipartite & B ) : _B( other._B ) , _i( 0 ) {}
        row_iterator( const Bipartite & B , const int i ) : _B( other._B ) , _i( i ) {}
        row_iterator( const self_type & other ) : _B( other._B ) , _i( other._i ) {}
        self_type operator=( const self_type & other ) { _B = other._B; _i = other._i; return ( * this ); }
        self_type operator++()           { _i++; return ( * this ); } // PREFIX
        self_type operator++( int junk ) { self_type tmp = ( * this ); _i++; return tmp; } // POSTFIX  
        value_type & operator*() { return _i; }
        //value_type * operator->() { return & _i; }
        bool operator==( const self_type & rhs ) { return ( _i == rhs._i ) and ( _B == rhs._B ); }
        bool operator!=( const self_type & rhs ) { return ( _i != rhs._i ) or  ( _B != rhs._B ); }
        operator bool() { return _i < _B.num_rows(); }

        void test_func() {
            int i = ( * this );
            bool b = ( * this );
        }

    private:
        Bipartite & _B;
        int _i;
    };
```

Pay attention to the function `test_func()`. Now the question...

If I write

```
int i = ( * this );
```

I assume that `int operator*()` is called. On the other hand, if I write

```
bool b = ( * this );
```

I assume that `operator bool()` is called. Is this the case?

---

**EDIT**: Here I add the test that checks that the voted answer is correct.

```
#include <iostream>

class iter {
    public:
        typedef iter                         self_type;
        typedef int                          value_type;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag    iterator_category;
        iter( int imax ) : _i( 0 ) , _imax( imax ) {}
        value_type operator*() { return _i; }
        self_type operator++()           { _i++; return ( * this ); } // PREFIX
        self_type operator++( int junk ) { self_type tmp = ( * this ); ++( * this ); return tmp; } // POSTFIX  
        operator bool() { return _i < _imax; }
        void test() {
            bool b = ( * this );
            int q = ( * this );
            int i = ( * ( * this ) );
            std::cout << "b = " << b << " , q = " << q << " , i = " << i << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        int _i;
        int _imax;
};

int main( void ) {

    iter it( 10 );
    while ( ( bool ) it ) {
        it.test();
        it++;
    }

}
```

The output, reads:

```
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 0
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 1
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 2
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 3
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 4
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 5
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 6
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 7
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 8
b = 1 , q = 1 , i = 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second assumption is correct. Your first is not.

You must keep in mind that the type of `this` is `row_iterator*`, thus, the result type of `*this` is `row_iterator`, which, due to the existence of your `operator bool()` can be contextually converted to bool which is what happens in your second assignment (`bool b = *this`).

In your first assignment (`int i = (*this)`) there is no suitable conversion from `row_iterator` to `int`. There is, however, a conversion to `bool` and converting a `bool` to an `int` is possible too, so in its current state, your first assignment will result in `i` being 1 if `operator bool()` returns true and 0 otherwise.

In order to fix this, you need to dereference `this` twice.

To elaborate, [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) (which is what's happening here) consists of up to three conversions:

> 1. zero or one *standard conversion sequence*
> 2. zero or one *user-defined conversion*
> 3. zero or one *standard conversion sequence*.

Standard conversion sequences consist of:

> 1. zero or one *lvalue transformation*
> 2. zero or one *numeric promotion or conversion*
> 3. zero or one *function pointer conversion* (c++17 and up )
> 4. zero or one *qualification adjustment*

Since the standard conversion sequence does not allow pointers to be dereferenced, the only way dereferencing can occur during implicit conversion is if it is done in a user-defined conversion function.

Comment: Ah, you're right. `*this` is a `row_iterator&`, and `**this` is an `int&`.

Comment: It makes sense. I have tested it and it worked as you say. I will add the test.

Comment: @Juan I've added a brief explanation as to what's going on in the conversion for completeness' sake.